# Make icon above text for MFC Button

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I wanted to create CMFCButton dynamically at runtime (Icon with Text on the button). The icon is created successfully but I wanted to display the icon above text.

I want to implement "Image on Top" property found in Resource Editor for the button.

My Code:

```
CMFCButton* appButton = new CMFCButton;
appButton->Create( _T("MfcButton1"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, CRect(10, 10, 70, 50), this );
appButton->SetIcon( sfi.hIcon );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(according to the "NewControls" MFC sample).

To set an image in a CMFCButton use **CMFCButton::SetImage**.
To set the image above (or below) the text you can use the undocumented variable **m_bTopImage**

```
appButton->m_bTopImage = TRUE;
```

FYI: the complete samples can be downloaded from :
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5718